# Very Basic Cut/Paste VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Very new to VBA:

I am looking to cut data from cells C2 to the end of the column and paste that data, beginning in cell e2.

I understand this should be extremely simple, but I have tried a few things and am still stuck. The data gets cut directly, but cannot get it to paste.

Recent attempt:

```
Sub CutPaste_Data()
    
    Range("c2", Range("c2").End(xlDown)).Select
    
    Selection.Cut
    
    Range("e2", Range("e2").End(xlDown)).Select
    
    Selection.PasteSpecial
```

Comment: If you try this manually you'll see you cannot PasteSpecial after a Cut, only after a Copy.

Comment: `Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp)).Offset(0, 2).Value = Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp)).Value`

Answer (score 3):

Since you're new, I'll attempt to coerce some good habits with my example solution :)

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyData()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    With ws
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range(.Cells(2, 5), .Cells(lastRow, 5)).Value = .Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(lastRow, 3)).Value
        .Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(lastRow, 3)).Value = vbNullString
    End With
End Sub
```

Here are the good habits for your VBA code:

1. [Always use `Option Explicit`](https://riptutorial.com/excel-vba/example/3554/always-use--option-explicit-)
2. Always be clear on what [worksheet or range is being referenced](https://riptutorial.com/excel-vba/example/5110/qualifying-references)
3. Use intermediate variables (such as `lastRow`) to help yourself make your code more readable. Yes, it's a few extra lines of code. But in many instances it can make your code faster (if that's a concern), but you'll find readability  will always be a bigger help to you in the long run.
4. [Avoid using `Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10717999/4717755) in your code

Good luck!